# React-router: difference between history.push and location.href in flux app?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, html5-history

I'm a bit new with React, react-router, and flux, and I'm curious.
I'm curious, what's the difference between the 2 types of link click handling.
My feeling is `location.href` may "reset" the application, like if page was reloaded.
Is that right or wrong? And what's the difference between the 2 methods? Cause I'm not always able to use `history.push` in the application.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 4):

The HTML5 History API gives developers the ability to modify a website's URL without a full page refresh

whereas location.href will cause the page to refresh